# How can I translate in spanish \begin{theo} in enviroment mdframe?

Tags: mdframed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
%%%
\newcounter{theo}[section]\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}
\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}
%%%
\begin{theo}[Principios fundamentales de homogeneización]{thm:t1}
\begin{eqnarray}
    \bigtriangledown\cdot\tso{\sigma}=0 && \text{(Ecuación de equilibrio)}\\
    \tso{\sigma}=\tso{a(y)}:\epsilon && \text{(Ley constitutiva elástica esfuerzo )}\\
    \epsilon=\tso{E}+y_{3}\chi+\bigtriangledown^{sym} \tso{u} && \text{(Ley constitutiva elástica deformación)}\\
    \tso{\sigma}e_{3}=0 \hspace{2mm} sobre \hspace{2mm}\partial Y_{3}^{+}\hspace{2mm}\partial Y_{3}^{-} && \text{(Condición de esfuerzo en el plano 3 )}\\
    \tso{\sigma}\cdot\tso{n}\hspace{2mm} antiperiodic\hspace{2mm} on \hspace{2mm}\partial Y_{l} &&\text{(Condición de periodicidad del tensor tracción )}\\
    \tso{u}\hspace{2mm} periodic \hspace{2mm} on \hspace{2mm}\partial Y_{l} && \text{(Condición de periodicidad del desplazamiento)}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{theo}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately your posted code does not compile, as it seems to miss `\begin[document} ` and `\end[document}` . Please correct. Thank you

Comment: Just replace `{\strut Theorem~\thetheo}` with `{\strut Teorema~\thetheo}`.

Comment: You may also want to replace `\newcounter{theo}[section] \setcounter{theo}{0} \renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}` with `\newcounter{theo} \counterwithin{theo}{section}`. And, for crying out loud, do replace `\hspace{2mm} antiperiodic\hspace{2mm} on \hspace{2mm}` with `\text{ antiperiodic on }`.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to have a look at `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`, because the latter has been abandoned.

My guess is that you want to be able to reuse the code in different linguistic contexts. You can use a macro instead of hardwiring “Theorem” and define the macro according to the particular document's needs.

I also streamlined the code: with [`\NewDocumentEnvironment`](https://texdoc.org/serve/usrguide/0) you can specify the optional argument as `o` and its presence will make `\IfValueT{#1}{...}` to be used.

I changed `eqnarray` (that should never be used) into `alignat`. Note how to correctly insert text in math mode and finally `\nabla` instead of `\bigtriangledown`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newcounter{theo}
\counterwithin{theo}{section}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theo}{om}{%
  \refstepcounter{theo}%
  \mdfsetup{
    frametitle={
     \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
     \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]{\strut \bregyTheorem~\thetheo\IfValueT{#1}{:~#1}};
    },
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    linecolor=blue!20,
    linewidth=2pt,
    topline=true,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
  }
  \begin{mdframed}\label{#2}%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\newcommand{\tso}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand{\bregyTheorem}{Teorema}% for Spanish

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[Principios fundamentales de homogeneización]{thm:t1}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  &\nabla\cdot\tso{\sigma}=0 &\quad& \text{(Ecuación de equilibrio)}\\
  &\tso{\sigma}=\tso{a(y)}:\epsilon 
    && \text{(Ley constitutiva elástica esfuerzo )}\\
  &\epsilon=\tso{E}+y_{3}\chi+\nabla^{\mathrm{sym}} \tso{u}
    && \text{(Ley constitutiva elástica deformación)}\\
  &\tso{\sigma}e_{3}=0 \text{ sobre } \partial Y_{3}^{+}\;\partial Y_{3}^{-}
    && \text{(Condición de esfuerzo en el plano 3 )}\\
  &\tso{\sigma}\cdot\tso{n} \text{ antiperiodic on }\partial Y_{l}
    &&\text{(Condición de periodicidad del tensor tracción )}\\
  &\tso{u} \text{ periodic on } \partial Y_{l}
    && \text{(Condición de periodicidad del desplazamiento)}
\end{alignat}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Left alignment of the equations seems better to me. You can get the alignment in your picture, though, with

```
\begin{align}
  \nabla\cdot\tso{\sigma}=0
    &\quad\text{(Ecuación de equilibrio)}\\
  \tso{\sigma}=\tso{a(y)}:\epsilon
    &\quad \text{(Ley constitutiva elástica esfuerzo )}\\
  \epsilon=\tso{E}+y_{3}\chi+\nabla^{\mathrm{sym}} \tso{u}
    &\quad \text{(Ley constitutiva elástica deformación)}\\
  \tso{\sigma}e_{3}=0 \text{ sobre } \partial Y_{3}^{+}\;\partial Y_{3}^{-}
    &\quad \text{(Condición de esfuerzo en el plano 3 )}\\
  \tso{\sigma}\cdot\tso{n} \text{ antiperiodic on }\partial Y_{l}
    &\quad\text{(Condición de periodicidad del tensor tracción )}\\
  \tso{u} \text{ periodic on } \partial Y_{l}
    &\quad \text{(Condición de periodicidad del desplazamiento)}
\end{align}
```

[image]